# Printer declaration in Java

Tags: java, bison

I'm using Bison with `%define parse.error verbose` option to provide more informative error messages. Bison generates parser in Java language. Currently parser prints messages such as

`syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting RPAREN or COMMA`

I wanted to use `%printer` declarations to replace default token names, but I have found in bison docs that they are not supported in Java:

`Java parsers do not support %printer, as toString() can be used to print the semantic values. This however may change (in a backwards-compatible way) in future versions of Bison.`

Each token has declared sematic value's type, e.g. `%token <Symbol> IDENTIFIER` where `Symbol` has custom `toString()` method.

But still I do not know how to tell parser to call `toSting()` method instead of printing default token's name.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Grzegorz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the tokens with an alias:

```
%token <id> IDENTIFIER "identifier"
%token RPAREN "right parenthesis"
```

The `%printer` function wouldn't be used in an error message, even if it were implemented in Java, because the error is talking about tokens which *have not been encountered*, whereas the `%printer` method is used to print the *semantic value* of tokens which were encountered. The unencountered token does not exist, and therefore its semantic value cannot be printed, only its description.

Comment: One of the tokens in the error message is not "unencountered", it's a lookahead token.  So it does have an associated semantic value (in `yylval`, as set by the lexer), it just hasn't been shifted on the parser stack yet.  So one would think `%printer` would be used for it, but it isn't.